# How can I implement a File_name field that excludes my file path and contains only the file name [Django models]

Tags: django, forms, file, django-models, filenames

I am developing an app in Django.
In my template I have a fileform that allows users to store files in a model, they are stored in my media_root/uploaded_files/ directory:

```
class my_model (models.Model):

    file_obj = models.FileField(upload_to='uploaded_files/', blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):    
        return  "%s"  %  (self.file_obj)
```

But in my admin section, accessing the model my_model I get file names like:

•   uploaded_ files/file_1
•   uploaded_ files/file_2
•   uploaded_ file /file_3

While I want:

•   file_1
•   file_2
•   file_3

How can I implement a File_name field that excludes “uploaded_ files” and contains only the file name?

Comment: Look at the [docs for `name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.name), it includes the path. If you just want to get the name of the file, use the `os.path` utilities to extract the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

In my admin.py:

```
class my_modelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def file_name(self):
            import os
            return os.path.basename(self.file_obj.name)


    list_display = [file_name]
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.name), the `name` property returns the path of the file relative to your storage root.

If you want to get just the name of the file, use `os.path.basename()` to extract the name.